# Converting texts in to csv file under separate columns

Tags: python-3.x, csv, text, export-to-csv

I have the following in a .txt file

```
1.['LG','Samsung','Asus','HP','Apple','HTC']
2.['covid','vaccine','infection','cure','chloroquine']
3.['p2p','crypto','bitcoin','litecoin','blockchain']
```

How do I convert the above into a csv file under different columns?

My current code is this

```
import csv

with open('Full_txt_results.txt', 'r') as in_file:
    stripped = (line.strip() for line in in_file)
    lines = (line.split(",") for line in stripped if line)
    with open('textlabels.csv', 'w') as out_file:
        writer = csv.writer(out_file)
        writer.writerows(lines)
```

the code currently gives the result in the following format in csv

```
Column 1  Column2   column 3   column 4     Column 5        column 6
['LG'    'Samsung'  'Asus'       'HP'       'Apple'        'HTC']
['covid' 'vaccine' 'infection'  'cure'    'chloroquine']
['p2p'   'crypto'  'bitcoin'   'litecoin'  'blockchain']
```

The texts are spilled in to different columns.

Ideal output required is in the below format

```
Column 1  Column2     column 3   
LG        Covid         p2p
Samsung   Vaccine      crypto
Asus      Infection    bitcoin
HP        cure         litecoin
Apple     chloroquine  blockchain  
HTC
```

Comment: what is your error?

Comment: No error as such. Just not getting the right format. please see the current output above and ideal output required.

Comment: SO is NOT a: write code service. If you need help with specific error, then it is appropriate to ask for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ast` module to convert string to list object and then write to csv using `writerow` method

**Ex:**

```
import csv
import ast

with open('Full_txt_results.txt') as in_file, open('textlabels.csv', 'w', newline="") as out_file:
    writer = csv.writer(out_file)
    data = [ast.literal_eval(line.strip().split(".")[1]) for line in in_file]      #If you do not have column number(1.,2.,...) Use [ast.literal_eval(line.strip()) for line in in_file]
    for row in zip(*data):
        writer.writerow(row)
```

---

**Demo**:

```
import csv
import ast

with open(filename) as in_file, open(outfile, 'w', newline="") as out_file:
    writer = csv.writer(out_file)
    data = [ast.literal_eval(line.strip()) for line in in_file]
    for row in zip(*data):
        writer.writerow(row)
```

**SRC txt file**

```
['LG','Samsung','Asus','HP','Apple','HTC']
['covid','vaccine','infection','cure','chloroquine']
['p2p','crypto','bitcoin','litecoin','blockchain']
```

**Output:**

```
LG,covid,p2p
Samsung,vaccine,crypto
Asus,infection,bitcoin
HP,cure,litecoin
Apple,chloroquine,blockchain
```

Comment: After parsing the first row of data . Also I am getting the error `ValueError: malformed node or string: ["['LG','Samsung','Asus','HP','Apple','HTC']"]`